# Replacing ASTA as a middletier solution

Tags: delphi, client-server, intraweb, datasnap, remobjects

I'm currently using Delphi7 along with ASTA to handle my client server communications to an Advantage DB.

I'm moving to Rad Studio XE Enterprise and am looking to switch to a different but similar solution as the future of ASTA has become somewhat uncertain.  As this will be a large investment in time, and probably money, I've been researching the options but have reached a trees vs forest situation.

I'll list some basic points on what I need, and if anyone can suggest a specific combination of technologies and products I should focus on that may help meet those needs, I will greatly appreciate it.  I really just need to replace and/or improve the communication and encryption abilities that ASTA has provided with something current and under active development and support.

  -I'll be using Delphi XE.

  -Applications will be Win32, server will run on Windows.

  -IIS is not allowed.

  -VPN requirement is not allowed.

  -Socket communication must support AES encryption natively or through third party addon.

  -Some basic browser based application access would be a bonus, IF it is capable of strong security.

  -Support for linux, mac, mobile is a very low priority.

  -I'll need to be able to meet NIST 800-53/FIPS 140-2 compliancy, but won't need certification. (as they pertain to communication and encryption)

As this is my first question, please let me know if I can better phrase or detail what I need.

Thanks for any direction you guys can give.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclaimer: i work for RemObjects Software.

> -I'll be using Delphi XE.

Data Abstract supports Delphi 7 and Delphi 2007 thru XE, and we regularly add support for new versions of Delphi as soon as possible (ie when XE2 comes)

> -Applications will be Win32, server will run on Windows.

We support that yes.

> -IIS is not allowed.

Hosting in IIS is an *option* in data Abstract, nut not a requirement. in fact, our preferred/suggested model is using standalone server executables, which you could install a service or run manually, that open their own orts and are full servers. these could be based on HTTP, or on other protocols (such as out more "to the metal" TCP or Super TCP channels)

> -VPN requirement is not allowed.

DA wont need (but will of course work thru) VPNs.

> -Socket communication must support AES encryption natively or through third
>   party addon.

DA supports AES out of the box, as well as HTTPS (the latter depending on the underlying communication methods you choose).

> -Some basic browser based application access would be a bonus, IF it is
>   capable of strong security.

DA servers can provide access via JSON and REST/OData *in addition* to the regular client/server communication that DA provides for its own clients. this way, you don;t have to compromise wrt how your "real" desktop clients talk to your server, but still have the flexibility to let other clients (including web based ones) talk to your server as well, using open standards.

> -Support for linux, mac, mobile is a very low priority.

DA/Delphi supports Linux thru FPC (Mac too, but we consider Mac/FPC to be rougher territory ;), and will add support for Linux and Mac via Delphi once Embarcadero ships that.

Of course we also have separate editions of DA for native Mac/iOS development (in Xcode) and for .NET (which thru Mono is a good way to support Linux), if you ever need to go there.

> -I'll need to be able to meet NIST 800-53/FIPS 140-2 compliancy, but
>   won't need certification. (as they
>   pertain to communication and
>   encryption)

that's the only question i don;t have an answer to, as i'm not aware of the details of this standard. But if you have specific technical questions with regard to that, please don't hesitate to contact me, or our support team via support@remobjects.com

hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for everyone's feedback.  I'll be trying out Remobjects as it seems to be the best option for what I need as far as communication.  I'll also be attempting to use Eldos SecureBlackBox to handle the encryption.

Answer (score 3):

We recently finished rewriting our application using DataAbstract from RemObjects. It's a little bit of a learning curve, but once you're over it you'll find it a highly rewarding experience. Here are the questions I can answer:

- I'll be using Delphi XE - *XE is
  supported.*
- Applications will be Win32, server
  will run on Windows - *DA works with
  Windows and MAC.*
- IIS is not allowed - *No need for IIS*
- Socket communication must support AES
  encryption natively or through third
  party addon - *AES is supported out of
  the box.*

Answer (score 3):

We use RemObjects SDK for our thin client software:

- thin client with TMS Smooth Controls, written in D2010
- communication (binary, TCP) with server (D2010, Windows Service)
- With RO SDK you can easily create your own (remote) functions, with
  special parameters, return values, etc. All business logic is server side.
- we do not use DataAbstract (very database/table oriented, don't like to use Javascript for business rules)
- compression/encryption is supported, but we do not use them (internal network)
- you can also use HTTP+SOAP, we use IndyHTTPServer component with some special handling to create some simple webpages too. Link: http://blog.delphiaddict.com/?p=171

RO SDK works very good and is of high quality!

Comment: Just to note that DataAbstract business rules scripting component uses Pascal as well as javascript.

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest to talk directly to vendors:

- `RemObjects` regarding `RO SDK` + `DA` - support@remobjects.com
- `Components4Developers` regarding `kbmMW` - support@components4developers.com
- `RealThinClient` regarding `RTC SDK` - devsupport@realthinclient.com

Sure, they will give you detailed answers.